# Can I force svcutil.exe to generate data contracts for a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

I would like to force `svcutil` to generate all data contracts in an assembly that is used by WCF, regardless of whether or not a type is referenced by a given operation contract.

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo { }

[DataContract]
public class Bar : Foo { }

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Get(Foo foo);
}
```

Given this setup I cannot get `svcutil` to generate a version of `Bar` as there are no operation contracts that currently reference it.  Is there a way to force `svcutil` to generate the data contract for `Bar`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a KnownType attribute to the Foo class

```
[KnownType(typeof(Bar))]
[DataContract]
public class Foo { }
```