# WCF—Separating Contract from Implementation

Tags: wcf, datacontract

Is there anyway one can separate the contract (data members) from the implementation (remaining methods used only by the service internals) of a given class marked as `DataContract` in two different assemblies? Doing this within the same assembly is easy with the `partial` keyword, but I need to have them in separate assemblies.

Comment: Add some example of what you want to do. It is not clear from your description.

Comment: What benefit do you think you'll get from separating the data structures into interfaces? For classes with actual **functionality**, it makes sense so you can implement a stub/mock for unit testing - but for a data class....

Comment: @marc_s Data classes may have members of another data class inside them, and so on. In this case, "mocking" because rather problematic. Of course, separating data contracts into partial classes will not solve this, as the data types will still be concrete types. In fact, I can see of now way of solving this with just types/inheritance/interfaces in C#.

Answer (score -1):

[DataContract] is something you typically use on Interfaces rather than Classes. So put your interfaces in a separate assembly from your implementation classes and you'll get what you want.

Comment: interface is not allowed to be marked as DataContract. See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4720963/52277 of ​http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720730/wcf-and-interfaces-on-data-contracts