# How to make WCF Data Service's entities implement an interface?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, interface, wcf-data-services

I have an EF CF model generated from .tt file so each entity gets an interface, say `IEntity`.

Then I have a WCF Data Service exposing the model.

But when I add a service reference to this service, resulting entities have no such interface, so I can't use generics against them.

How can I workaround that?

Comment: Why don't you just reuse the same model at the client side?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Then using WCF DS will make no sense at all. But I still want to use it (or I didn't understand your question, sorry). Don't expose the model but provide REST access to it.

Comment: I think Wiktor was asking to just share the client and server types. You can put them in a separate assembly and use that both in client and server. You can still WCF DS since you want to serialize/deserialize these types in odata over the web. In other words, instead of doing add service reference, you just use the same types from the shared assembly and use those types from both client and server.

Comment: @Pratik: Would you mind please show a working example as an answer? I would be glad to try it and accept if it will work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720730/wcf-and-interfaces-on-data-contracts) is a detailed explanation why you do not get the IEntity on the client. If approach with sharing assembly does not work for you, you can still do the following. Instead of IEntity create EntityBase. Than add to this attributes like `[KnownType(typeof(MyEntity1))], [KnownType(typeof(MyEntity2))]` and so on. You are using a tt, so you will be able twick it to generate EntityBase and knowntype attributes with all model types automatically. Than on the client you will get base class for all your entities.