# WCF and IList of ISomething

Tags: c#, wcf, ilist

I'm wondering how to make this object available through WCF:

```
[DataContract]
public class A : IA
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<IB> ListOfB { get; set; } 
}

public interface IA
{
    List<IB> ListOfB { get; set; }
}
```

with `IB` interface of class `B`.

Generated XSD is:

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" minOccurs="0" name="ListOfB" nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayOfanyType"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="A" nillable="true" type="tns:A"/>
</xs:schema>
```

ArrayOfanyType -> I'm feeling that it can't work since `IB` can't be tagged `[DataContract]`.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4720963/870604

Comment: @ken2k +1, you answered his question before me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the serializer to interpret your contract they need to be expressed in terms of concrete types rather than interfaces. If you change your code to this (and annotate class B with the appropriate `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes, you should be good to go.

```
[DataContract]
public class A
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<B> ListOfB { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Sure. But I still need my `A` to have list of `IB` and not `IB` directly (theses objects are shared, and `A` implements `IA`, `IA` should not know `B` but only `IB`...

Comment: @FrancoisB. I understand that's what you want but you can't do that. The contract needs to be based on concrete types.