# Interfaces in WCF and Integration Tests

Tags: wcf

So is it that you shouldn't or can't use Interfaces in methods you are exposing or in the DTOs you are exposing to the client in a WCF service?  Because if I have this for example:

```
public class MyCustomDTO
{
    public ITransaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
IPaymentRequest SendTransaction(PreAuthorizeRequest request);
```

I notice that when I try to create integration tests to prove that the wsdl can be used and make successful calls, my ITransaction and IPaymentRequest are serialized and exposed through the service client as "object" probably because it doesn't know what kind of object to expose in the contract right?

so is it you can't create methods or DTOs with Interfaces in them as part of the contract you are exposing to the outside world that consumes your WCF service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720730/wcf-and-interfaces-on-data-contracts/4720963#4720963

Comment: thanks.....did not see that yet

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF to connect two .NET instances and you share your contracts as a common contract assembly between the two instead of using the auto-generated client from the wsdl, then it works. However, WCF is about interoperability and you may want to add a non-.NET client down the road so you should only use actual types so your service will work well with all the other languages out there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by share contracts as a common contract instead of using the auto-gened client from the wsdl

Comment: If you put your Service Interface and all DTOs that it uses in an assembly of it's own, you can reference this assembly in your client and use those classes to communicate with the service. The client that is autogenerated from the wsdl is just another copy of your classes, generated from the wsdl.