# Convert IEnumerable<object> frow WCF to another local IEnumerable<object> is that possible?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, casting, dapper

I have this function in a WCF service:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> ListProducts()
{
    return dal.RunDapper<Product>("listarProdutos");
}
```

It will execute a proc with Dapper and map data with this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int PRODUCTID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PRODUCTNAME { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string COMPANYNAME { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CATEGORYNAME { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal UNITPRICE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int UNITINSTOCK { get; set; }
}
```

In my Local Model:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> ListarProdutos()
{
    var retorno = WCF.ListProducts();
    return retorno.Cast<Product>();
}
```

and my local Product class has same properties:

```
public class Product
{
    public int PRODUCTID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCTNAME { get; set; }
    public string COMPANYNAME { get; set; }
    public string CATEGORYNAME { get; set; }
    public decimal UNITPRICE { get; set; }
    public int UNITINSTOCK { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ProductDB produtos = new ProductDB();
    var model = produtos.ListProducts();

    return View(model);
}
```

My View model:

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PRODUCTNAME)</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.COMPANYNAME)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CATEGORYNAME)</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UNITPRICE)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UNITINSTOCK)</td>
</tr>
```

I am getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type `ModeloTemplate.NorthWindWCF.Product` to
>   type `ModeloTemplate.Models.Product`.

Comment: Well, they aren't the same type, thats why you cant assign one to another. There isn't an explicit/implicit cast between one another.

Answer (score 1):

The WCF service reference created a type for `Product` as `ModeloTemplate.NorthWindWCF.Product`.  You defined a type (as you said, locally) as `ModeloTemplate.Models.Product`.  These are two different, unrelated types and cannot be cast back and forth automatically.  Check out [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Plus one for AutoMapper (although it might be overkill if you only have this one mapping between classes). Using Linq you could do a 'wcfProducts.Select(p => new Local.Product{...})' to quickly map out a new list of the local version of the product.

Answer (score 0):

Your local model is missing the attributes, if you want to use a local object instead of the data contract object you need to either:

- Overload the = operator and match up the properties and assign the data contract object to the local one or
- Create a class that will map the data contract to your local object.

Alternatively use the data contract object in your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As an extension - use an interface in your application that the `DataContract` just happens to implement. This decouples your application from your data layer.

Comment: Wcf will require concrete classes for the data contacts and not an interface see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720730/wcf-and-interfaces-on-data-contracts